# git ruby script not working "must be run in a work tree"

Tags: ruby, git

Want to copy the contents of the CWD repo (bare) into the '../deploy' folder. The git command below works just fine on the Bash command line (with manual variable substitution) but always errors out when called using backticks in ruby. What's the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../deploy')
`GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
File.expand_path('../deploy')
```

will give you a path relative to your cwd, not relative to the Ruby script. Instead, you should use

```
File.expand_path('../deploy', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake. The target directory was misspelled and I never noticed due to tab completion.